# Recording user response times for a quiz

Tags: php, ajax, quiz

I am working on a simple quiz-type game in which the user basically is asked a series of questions and needs to provide an answer.

I'm trying to find a solid/robust way of recording how long it takes for the user to answer each question. This is a web-based game so I am using JavaScript and PHP. I am very inexperienced, so I suspect this is not the best way to do it; at least I hope it's not because it seems very weak. I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to go about making a more full-proof solution. It's not critical that the time be accurate to the millisecond I'm just looking to build something that will be consistent and accurate to within a second or two.

The reason I'm doing it like this rather than just recording the time in the browser is because, as I understand it, the data could theoretically be altered by the user. This is also why I don't send that correct and answers to the browser until the user provides an answer.

Here is my current approach:

```
<?php
/* get_game_data.php
 * 
 * user clicks button to start game
 * and triggers ajax request sent to this file
 */
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET')
{
    if(isset($_GET['gamesettings'])){///check certian user defined game options are set

        require 'classes/Database.php';

        date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

        $_SESSION['app_start'] = new DateTime('NOW');////store time at which game/first question starts
        $_SESSION['app_index'] = 0;

        if($_GET['app'] === 'aural') {

           $db = new Database();

           $gameData = getGameData($db);///just an example
           //etc...
           //query database for game data, i.e. the questions,
           echo json_encode($gameData['questions]);//then send back to browser

           $_SESSION['right_answers'] = $gameData['answers'];///store the right answers to varify against user answers later


        }

    }
}
?>



<?php
/* post_game_data.php
 * 
 * user answers question in a textbox etc.
 * then clicks a submit button which posts the answer to 
 * this file via ajax again
 */
session_start();

function getTimeTaken($startDTO) {

    $endDTO     = new DateTime('NOW');
    $timeDiff   = $startDTO->diff($endDTO);
    $timeTaken  = $timeDiff->format('%s');

    return $timeTaken;
}



date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if(
       isset($_POST['user_answer']) &&
       isset($_SESSION['app_index'])     
    )
    {
        $index = $_SESSION['app_index'];///current question in the game
        $len = count($_SESSION['words']);///number of questions in the game
        $userAns = $_POST['user_answer'];
        $rightAns = $_SESSION['right_answers'];


        if(isset($_SESSION['app_start']))////if this is the first question 
        { 
            $responseTime = getTimeTaken($_SESSION['app_start']);
            unset($_SESSION['app_start']);
            $_SESSION['question_start'] = new DateTime('NOW'); 
        } 
        else if(isset($_SESSION['question_start']))///not the first question
        {  
            $responseTime = getTimeTaken($_SESSION['question_start']);
            $_SESSION['question_start'] = new DateTime('NOW');
        }


        if($index < $len)
        {
            $crtAns = $rightAns[$index];
            $mark = ($userAns == $crtAns)?1:0;///check user answer against correct answer
            $_SESSION['app_index']++;
            echo json_encode(array($crtAns, $mark, $responseTime));////send right answer to broswer with mark and response time
        }


    }

}
?>
```

This works pretty much as I would like it to right now but I don't have a live server to test it on, only Apache local host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some simple stuff, 
a common.php file for common code used by both files. DRY don't repeat yourself.

Writing a script like you have is fine, the points i have noted will help you if you come back to maintain it in a year or so, and have forgotten how it works.

The bulk of programming jobs are about maintaining a code base, not creating new stuff, so if you can learn how to make maintenance easier, it will be beneficial for you in the long run. (I wish i had learnt this stuff much earlier on)

I have added inline comments explaining the changes i made

```
<?php
/* common.php */
require 'classes/Database.php';

session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

?>



<?php
/* get_game_data.php
 *
 * user clicks button to start game
 * and triggers ajax request sent to this file
 */

require 'common.php';

// moved into common.php
// session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET')
{
    if(isset($_GET['gamesettings'])){///check certian user defined game options are set

        // moved into common.php
//        require 'classes/Database.php';

        // moved into common.php
//        date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

        $_SESSION['app_start'] = new DateTime('NOW');////store time at which game/first question starts
        $_SESSION['app_index'] = 0;

        // warning if $_GET['app'] not set this will get a warning notice, we can never trust GET/POST data
        // if($_GET['app'] === 'aural') {
        if(isset($_GET['app']) && $_GET['app'] === 'aural') {

            $db = new Database();

            $gameData = getGameData($db);///just an example
            //etc...
            //query database for game data, i.e. the questions,

            // i prefer to do my internal logic before i output data. this way if something fails i can handle it prior to responding to the user
            $_SESSION['right_answers'] = $gameData['answers'];///store the right answers to varify against user answers later

            echo json_encode($gameData['questions']);//then send back to browser



        }

    }
}
?>



<?php
/* post_game_data.php
 *
 * user answers question in a textbox etc.
 * then clicks a submit button which posts the answer to
 * this file via ajax again
 */

require 'common.php';

// moved into common.php
//session_start();




// moved into common.php
// date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    // what you have done is not bad, i just prefer to have all user supplied data handled in one place, POST/GET
    // so i know that everything beyond here has been sanitized
//    if(
//       isset($_POST['user_answer']) &&
//       isset($_SESSION['app_index'])
//    )

    $userAns = isset($_POST['user_answer']) ? $_POST['user_answer'] : null;

    // good variable names can also help reduce the need for comments
    // which of these two following variable names are easier to understand

    // $index = $_SESSION['app_index'];///current question in the game
    $current_question_index = isset($_SESSION['app_index']) ? $_SESSION['app_index'] : null;

    if($userAns != null && $current_question_index != null)
    {

        // same here with variable naming
        // if you are going to maintain these scripts over time, you need to make it easier to remember what is going on

        // $len = count($_SESSION['words']);///number of questions in the game
        $num_questions = count($_SESSION['words']);

        // handled above, no need to repeat
        //      $userAns = $_POST['user_answer'];

        $rightAns = $_SESSION['right_answers'];


        // why use a comment here that could change over time when you can make an easily understandable function name instead
        // if(isset($_SESSION['app_start']))////if this is the first question
        if (is_first_question())
        {
            $responseTime = getTimeTaken($_SESSION['app_start']);
            unset($_SESSION['app_start']);

            // $_SESSION['question_start'] = new DateTime('NOW');
            start_question_timer();
        }
        // else if(isset($_SESSION['question_start']))///not the first question        
        else if(is_question_started())///not the first question
        {
            $responseTime = getTimeTaken($_SESSION['question_start']);

           // $_SESSION['question_start'] = new DateTime('NOW');
            start_question_timer();
        }

        // which of these two is going to be easier to understand next year when you come back to maintain your script
        if ($current_question_index < $num_questions) {
    //    if($index < $len)
        {
            $crtAns = $rightAns[$current_question_index];

            // this is probably overkill in this case, but again why write a comment when you can write a nice function name
            // $mark = ($userAns == $crtAns)?1:0;///check user answer against correct answer
            $mark = mark_user_answer($userAns, $crtAns);

            // easy function names to make the code more understandable
            // $_SESSION['app_index']++;
            move_to_next_question();

            // given your if {} elseif {} statement above, $responseTime may not have been set, as there is no default case
            // this should be handled properly
            echo json_encode(array($crtAns, $mark, $responseTime));////send right answer to broswer with mark and response time
        }


    }

}


// move functions below main code as what is most important should come first
// perhaps this function could be called elapsedTimeInSeconds, 
// get infers you are getting a value, and there is no indication what the return type might be
function getTimeTaken($startDTO) {

    // good variable naming, easy to understand what is happening
    $endDTO     = new DateTime('NOW');
    $timeDiff   = $startDTO->diff($endDTO);
    $timeTaken  = $timeDiff->format('%s');

    return $timeTaken;
}


function is_first_question() {
    return isset($_SESSION['app_start']);
}

function is_question_started() {
    return isset($_SESSION['question_start'];
}

//
function mark_user_answer($user_answer, $correct_answer) {
    return ($user_answer == $correct_answer) ? 1 : 0;
}

function move_to_next_question() {
    $_SESSION['app_index']++;
}

function start_question_timer() {
    $_SESSION['question_start'] = new DateTime('NOW');}
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will study this carefully. I posted this mainly just as a proof of concept to see if people thought using sessions like this was a reliable/acceptable way to record user response times. However, there's plenty of great general programming stuff in here that I need to learn too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Matt.

Basically, the idea is correct - start the timer on the server side before the question is send to the user and calculate the duration on the response received. Using `DateTime` for that is also a great idea, in my opinion.

An alternative solution for you would be storing your gamers response time in the database, but this is a bit more complex. Please feel free to contact me in case you need an advise on that.

The only advise I have for you - try using OOP concepts in your code. All the rest is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will eventually be storing the response times in a database. I just wanted to see if using PHP like this was a suitable mechanism for accurately recording the time.